# EF Power Tools Beta 4 documentation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-power-tools

I can't seem to find much documentation for the code that Power Tools Beta 4 generates. I'm particularly interested in how to modify the code when new table fields are added, and how to add relationships. Where can I find a description of all the code pieces that are generated?

Also, I thought there was a way to regenerate and overwrite the Power Tools code after it has been generated but I just get errors when I try to do that. Do I need to delete all the generated entities in order to re-generate?